# Querying xml parent node attribute from child node

Tags: c#, xml, linq, excel, interop

I am working with an xml similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Results>
  <Pattern Name="Substitution">
    <TestList>
      <Test>
        <Inputs>
          <Variable Name="A" Value="-1" />
          <Variable Name="B" Value="20" />
        </Inputs>
        <Outputs>
          <Variable Name="A" Value="-1" />
          <Variable Name="B" Value="20" />
        </Outputs>
      </Test>
      <Test>
        <Inputs>
          <Variable Name="A" Value="-1" />
          <Variable Name="B" Value="20" />
        </Inputs>
        <Outputs>
          <Variable Name="A" Value="-1" />
          <Variable Name="B" Value="20" />
        </Outputs>
      </Test>
    </TestList>
  </Pattern>
  <Pattern Name="MinMax">
    <TestList>
      <Test>
        <Inputs>
          <Variable Name="A" Value="-1" />
          <Variable Name="B" Value="20" />
        </Inputs>
        <Outputs>
          <Variable Name="A" Value="-1" />
          <Variable Name="B" Value="20" />
        </Outputs>
      </Test>
      <Test>
        <Inputs>
          <Variable Name="A" Value="-1" />
          <Variable Name="B" Value="20" />
        </Inputs>
        <Outputs>
          <Variable Name="A" Value="-1" />
          <Variable Name="B" Value="20" />
        </Outputs>
      </Test>
    </TestList>
  </Pattern>
</Results>
```

I am writing the values from the test to an Excel worksheet using linq and excel interop.

```
var tests = from test in document.Descendants("Test").Descendants("Inputs")
            select new
            {
                inputNames = test.Elements("Variable").Attributes("Name")
            };

foreach (var test in tests)
{
    valueRow = valueMatch.Row;

    foreach (var inputName in test.inputNames)
    {
        if (valueSection.Find(inputName.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, XlLookAt.xlWhole) != null)
        {
             workSheetTwo.Cells[valueRow, valueColumn] = inputName.NextAttribute.Value;                       
             ++valueRow;
        }
    }

    ++valueColumn;
}
```

Writing the values to the Excel worksheet is working fine, but I also need to write the values with different cell background colors based on the pattern name it is under.. (e.g. blue if Pattern Name="Substitution", yellow if Pattern Name="MinMax"). Is ir possible to get the value of the pattern name from "inputName"? I tried using `inputName.Parent.Element("Pattern").Attribute("Name").Value`.. But this returns an exception. What is the correct way to do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, instead of `Element("Pattern")` call [`Ancestors("Pattern").First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.ancestors.aspx) like this...

```
inputName.Parent.Ancestors("Pattern").First().Attribute("Name").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tests = from p in xdoc.Descendants("Pattern")
            from input in p.Descendants("Test").Elements("Inputs")
            select new {
                Pattern = p.Attribute("Name").Value,
                Variables = input.Elements("Variable").Attributes("Name") };
```